# Executing JS function after clicking button which is present inside form

Tags: magento

We have button "*create*" and onclick "*Create*" button, it will create *product programtically* and assign *custom image* to that product.

app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme3/template/aitcg - js_styles1.phtml

```
<script>

var Aitcg_View_Abstract = Class.create(
{

_getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div>' +
                '<button  onclick="return setproductlogin(\'<?php echo Mage::registry("current_product")->getId()?>\', event);setrequestlogin();"  id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}">create</button>' +
                '<button>reset</button>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },

initObservers: function() 
      { 
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {  
           $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.createDesignBut.bindAsEventListener(this));           
         } 
       }, 

createDesignBut: function(event) 
        { 
          Event.stop(event); 
          this.option.apply(); 
        },     
}); 

</script>
```

we are trying to do the same once we submit form by clicking "login button".
here we are creating product sucessfully, but `custom image` is not saving in server, to save custom image in server onclick "*login*" button, we are using same function that "create" button is using as below code :

app/design/frontend/rwd/Theme3/template/productlike - index.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('example/amasty/createSimpleProductAndRedirect', 
array('_secure'=>(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on'), 
'id' => Mage::registry('current_product')->getId())) ?>" id="ajaxlogin-login-form">

// code for email id and password //

<button onclick="initObservers()" type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" 
name="send" id="send2"><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span>
</button>

</form>
```

but still custom image is not saving in server onclick "login" button.

where i done wrong here ?

Comment: The 'create' button in `aitcg - js_styles1.phtml` [is intended to?] calls `setrequestlogin` after calling `setproductlogin`.  It's not clear from what you have posted if calling `setproductlogin` is the same as doing a form submit - and it's likely that `setrequestlogin` is not being called by doing a form submit.

Comment: @Tibrogargan once user click on `create` button, than it will display `pop up box` , in pop up , we are displying form to login to site [ email id , pw, login button ]  , also if user click on `create` button we are creating new row in datbase [ nothing but the creating product ] and assigning custom image to that product. after click on `login` button also we are creating new product, but image is not assigning to product. because image is not creating in server......

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in code you have not included in your question

Comment: Just to be clear: If any of this process is intended to be performed by `setrequestlogin` then it will not work, since `setrequestlogin` is never called.

Comment: @Tibrogargan this function `initObservers()` is ` is responsible for creating `custom image` in server once we click on `create` button,  so i am using same function for `login button` also

Comment: @Tibrogargan can you please tell how i can call both functions for login button : `setrequestlogin(); & initObservers()`

Comment: No sir, it is not.  All `initObservers` does is attach a function as an observer to a click event.  Since you are dynamically creating the button there is a fair chance you're calling `initObservers` before the button even exists.

Comment: @Tibrogargan now is  i need to call only `setrequestlogin` , is that enough ? or what i need to do to save custom image after click on `login` button....

Comment: No offense, but how would I know?  You have not posted any of the code that you're trying to call.  Please read [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and post an [mcve]

Comment: @Tibrogargan thanks for guiding me, i will update question soon......

Comment: Your form calls `initObservers` in the submit button's `onclick`.  This will attach observers to buttons in the current page, but since submit buttons cause navigation, even if the action/destination is the same page, the page will reload and all observers would be removed - so calling `initObservers` is effectively doing nothing when used in this way.